# Does modifying files dates trigger time Machine backups?

Tags: time-machine

I'm having glitches with my photos library (300 GB) that could be solved by using the "touch" command, which modifies the modify-date of files.

My question :
Will this trigger a Time Machine backup, for every file which date has been modified ?

Conversely, if I modify a modify-date (for example using the touch command) and set it back to its former value afterwards, will the file still being back-upped ?

More generally, does modifying the creation date and the modification date of a file trigger a backup ? (I would like to change the creation date of the pics to the date when they were shot)

Thanks